# Count if value is not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count all cells which are `NOT(ISBLANK())`.

I tried this:

[image]

Why does this does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the right syntax for the `COUNTIF` function. For more, see the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-a8b3d1c2-309b-4e44-9047-e1746e90e55c?CorrelationId=2ff2559e-62d1-4e3a-9a4b-7539be32ed02&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Instead, you can use this regular formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))
```

or this array formula

```
=SUM(--NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))
```

The latter must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, my problem is that it seems that even though I dropped in the 'blank' cells this string: "", they are not blank. How could I just count for a specific word, like `NO_MATCH`?

Comment: To count all non-blanks, you could use {=SUM(IF(LEN(A:A)>0,1,0))} (Again, this would need to be entered using ctrl + shift + enter). For a specific word, you could use the normal Countif: =COUNTIF(A:A,"NO_MATCH")

Comment: @mrquad: Well, you're shifting the goalposts. That's a new question. Please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B8,"<>")
```

Comment: Interesting. I had never seen this usage of `"<>"` as a condition for `COUNTIF` and would not have guessed that it would work — but it does!

Comment: yep far from obvious but found it worked a while ago